# How to quickly solve $ 2 + \frac94t = \left( \frac{27+16\sqrt{2}}{8} \right)^{\frac23} $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, exponentiation, radicals

What is a quick and easy method to solve the equation $$ 2 + \frac94t = \left( \frac{27+16\sqrt{2}}{8} \right)^{\frac23} = \frac{\left( 16 \sqrt{2} + 27 \right)^\frac{2}{3}}{4} $$? I don't know how to find a cube root, nor do I have time to do so. This is part of a much bigger question which is supposed to be done in around $4-5$ minutes, and I can spend at the most $1 or 2$ minutes of this. How can I solve this quickly? The answer I'm supposed to get is 0.612 seconds.

Comment: If simplification isn't required this is a simple step, subtract 2 then multiply by 4/9.

Comment: Where did $27+16\sqrt{2}$ come from, if I can ask? I notice that it equals $3^{3}+(2\sqrt{2})^{3}$

Comment: @coffeemath I'm supposed to get  0.612 as t

Comment: @DanielLittlewood while doing this integration I ended up with this result: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2795261/how-to-solve-int-t-0t-sqrt22-25t-dt-1/2795279?noredirect=1#comment5763298_2795279

Comment: What's wrong with $t=((16\sqrt2+27)^{2/3}-8)/9$ as an answer? Do you *have* to compute it as a two-digit decimal?

Comment: Just multiply both sides by $4$, I guess, and then continue from there. @Hema 's comment is very good, though :)

Comment: @BarryCipra yes I have to

Comment: @Hema, unless you are allowed a calculator that'll compute cube (and square) roots, I don't see any quick way to get $0.612$ as the (approximate) answer.  If this is a time-limited exam question, it might be one the person who wrote the exam didn't think through too carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest form I can see is $$t=\frac 19\sqrt[3]{1241+864\sqrt{2}}-\frac 89$$

Done by evaluating $8^{\frac 23}$, and $(27+16\sqrt2)^2$, then rearranging for $t$.

From this we get $t\approx0.6116201124$. 
We can achieve something close by saying $\sqrt2\approx\ 1.5$, then $t\approx\frac 19(\sqrt[3]{2537}-8)\approx\frac19(13.5-8)=\frac 19(5.5)=\frac19\cdot\frac{11}{2}=\frac{11}{18}$

Hence we get $t\approx0.6\dot{1}$

Comment: Would the downvoter explain what the issue is?

Comment: you should be so lucky :-( .

Comment: OP does not want to evaluate the cube root.

Comment: Understood, however there's no way to get an answer without that. I attached to my answer a way to approximate it if this is non-calculator, using that $\sqrt2\approx 1.5$ and $13^3<2537<14^3$

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by $t$ and use the quadratic formula.

> $$t^2\bigg(\frac 94\bigg) - t\bigg(\frac{(27+16\sqrt{2})^{2/3}}{4}-2\bigg)+0=0.$$

Let $u=-\bigg(\dfrac{(27+16\sqrt{2})^{2/3}}{4}-2\bigg)=2-\dfrac{(27+16\sqrt{2})^{2/3}}{4}$ then $$\begin{align}t&=\frac{u\pm \sqrt{u^2-0}}{2(9/4)} \\ &=\frac{2u}{9}\text{ or } 0.\end{align}$$ The $u$'s cancel out or the $2$'s cancel out, and $2/4=1/2$.
But trivially, $t\neq 0$.

> > $$\therefore t=\frac {2u}{9}\tag*{$\bigcirc$}$$

Comment: You've got two solutions to a linear equation!

Comment: @DanielLittlewood Yes, true! $t$ is a **pronumeral**, not a **variable**. But... where did I go wrong? Is it the $\pm$ sign? Of course $u\neq 0$ so I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: You have multiplied $t$ on both sides. One of the solutions must be zero.it should be, $$t = \frac{2-u \pm \sqrt{(2-u)^2 - 0}}{2 \cdot 9/4}$$.

Comment: @Eval dammit, I thought I fixed the problem. Actually $-$ I did not! With this logic, $u$ can be *any* value...

Comment: Can anyone prove that closed form expression does not exist? I am highly suspicious about that.

Comment: @Eval ok I resubstituted $u$ and I think I got it correct this time...

Comment: @user477343 do you think there is any utility in doing this process? You will get same old expression.